# Cannot get the proper set of data using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch data from DB in an array using PHP and MySQL. In my case I am having 1 set of data in the given condition but the same set of data is coming multiple times. I am providing my code below.

```
$pro_id=$_GET['pro_id'];
$userid=$_GET['user_id'];


$sql="
SELECT s.id,
       s.voucher_code,
       s.merchant,
       s.date,
       s.receiver,
       s.sender,
       s.serial_no,
       s.image,
       s.expired_date,
       s.product_id,
       c.status,
       c.redeem_status,
       sup.supplier_id,
       sup.NAME,
       a.NAME         AS sender_name,
       v.discount,
       v.discount_type,
       v.voucher_amount,
       p.product_name AS pro_name
FROM   db_send_evoucher_code s
       INNER JOIN db_code c
               ON s.voucher_code = c.total_voucher_code
       INNER JOIN db_supplier sup
               ON s.merchant = sup.supplier_id
       INNER JOIN medilink_admin a
               ON s.sender = a.admin_id
       INNER JOIN db_voucher_code v
               ON c.voucher_code_id = v.voucher_code_id
       INNER JOIN db_product_info p
               ON s.product_id = p.pro_id
WHERE  s.receiver = '". $userid ."' 
  and  s.product_id = '". $pro_id ."'";

    $sqlqry = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sqlqry) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlqry)) {
            if ($row['discount_type'] == 'Flat') {
                $distype = 1;
            }
            if ($row['discount_type'] == 'percentage') {
                $distype = 2;
            }
            $data['data'][] = $data['data'][] = array("voucher_code" => $row['voucher_code'], "send_by" => $row['sender_name'], "image" => $row['image'], "expired_date" => $row['expired_date'], "supplier_name" => $row['name'], "sending_date" => $row['date'], "supplier_id" => $row['supplier_id'], "discount" => $row['discount'], "product_id" => $row['product_id'], "product_name" => $row['pro_name'], "redeem_status" => $row['redeem_status'], "voucher_amount" => $row['voucher_amount'], "discount_type" => $distype, "imagepath" => $imagepath);
            echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        }
    } else {
        $data['data'] = array();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Here in the given condition I have one set of data inside DB but it's coming two times. Here is my output:

```
{"data":[{"voucher_code":"FIFLTBH8567","send_by":"Medilink","image":"glotnzgrqbyb9_97yw155165stt9_eneoji_l.jpg","expired_date":"22-02-2016","supplier_name":"Eneoji","sending_date":"2016-02-18 16:11:35","supplier_id":"9","discount":"20","product_id":"52","product_name":"Eneoji Fomentation Therapy","redeem_status":"0","voucher_amount":"2000","discount_type":2,"imagepath":"http://li120-173.members.linode.com/crm_beta/upload/"},{"voucher_code":"FIFLTBH8567","send_by":"Medilink","image":"glotnzgrqbyb9_97yw155165stt9_eneoji_l.jpg","expired_date":"22-02-2016","supplier_name":"Eneoji","sending_date":"2016-02-18 16:11:35","supplier_id":"9","discount":"20","product_id":"52","product_name":"Eneoji Fomentation Therapy","redeem_status":"0","voucher_amount":"2000","discount_type":2,"imagepath":"http://li120-173.members.linode.com/crm_beta/upload/"}]}
```

Comment: Can you echo mysqli_num_rows($sqlqry) and see how much rows its there?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there is 2 lines with the same foreign key value in one of the inner joined table.
For ex,if you have 2 rows with total_voucher_code = "FIFLTBH8567" in table db_code, even if the reste of the row is different, you'll get this kind of unexpected result.

Comment: but when i am running only query inside `phphmyadmin` its giving the right result and that 1 row.

Comment: Ok,This was my mistake it was `$data['data'][]=$data['data'][]=` inside loop it made it `$data['data'][]=` and it gave the proper result.

Comment: So that was not about SQL ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your SELECT statement as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.id,s.voucher_code,s.merchant etc...
```

Comment: i did but no changes.

Answer (score -1):

Use distinct in your sql, so you don't get any duplicates rows:

```
$sql="select distinct s.id,s.voucher_code,s.merchant,s.date,s.receiver,s.sender,s.serial_no,s.image,s.expired_date,s.product_id,c.status,c.redeem_status,sup.supplier_id,sup.name,a.name AS sender_name,v.discount,v.discount_type,v.voucher_amount,p.Product_name AS pro_name 
from db_send_evoucher_code s 
INNER JOIN db_code c ON s.voucher_code=c.total_voucher_code 
INNER JOIN db_supplier sup ON s.merchant=sup.supplier_id 
INNER JOIN medilink_admin a ON s.sender=a.admin_id 
INNER JOIN db_voucher_code v ON c.voucher_code_id=v.voucher_code_id 
INNER JOIN db_product_info p ON s.product_id=p.pro_Id 
where s.receiver='".$userid ."' and s.product_id='".$pro_id."'";
```